# Is this static method thread safe or is synchronization needed

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a utility class that has one static method to modify values of the input Array List. This static method is invoked by a caller. The caller is used to process web service requests. For each request(per thread), the caller creates a new ArrayList and invokes the static method.

```
public class Caller{

   public void callingMethod(){

     //Get Cloned criteria clones a preset search criteria that has place holders for values and returns a new ArrayList of the original criteria. Not included code for the clone
     ArrayList<Properties> clonedCriteria = getClonedCriteria();

     CriteriaUpdater.update(clonedCriteria , "key1", "old_value1", "key1_new_value");
     CriteriaUpdater.update(clonedCriteria , "key2", "old_value2", "key2_new_value");

    //do something after the this call with the modified criteria arraylist
   }

}

public class CriteriaUpdater
{
    //updates the criteria, in the form of array of property objects, by replacing the token with the new value passed in
    public static void update(ArrayList<Properties> criteria, String key, String token, String newValue)
    {
        for (Properties sc: criteria)
        {
            String oldValue = sc.getProperty(key);
            if ((oldValue != null) && (oldValue.equals(token))) 
                sc.setProperty(key, newValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the criteria are cloned:

```
public synchronized static ArrayList<Properties> cloneSearchCriteria(ArrayList<Properties> criteria) { 
  if (criteria == null) return null; 
  ArrayList<Properties> criteriaClone = new ArrayList<Properties>(); 
  for (Properties sc : criteria) { 
    Properties clone = new Properties(); 
    Enumeration propertyNames = sc.propertyNames(); 
    while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) { 
      String key = (String) propertyNames.nextElement(); 
      clone.put(key, (String) sc.get(key)); 
    } 
    criteriaClone.add(clone);
  } 
  return criteriaClone; 
}
```

Given the above definitions, by not synchronizing the static method, would it still be able to correctly process concurrent method calls. My understanding is I have to synchronize this method for concurrency but wanted to confirm.
I understand each thread will have its own stack, but for static method it would be common to all threads - so in this case if we don't synchronize would it not cause a problem?
Appreciate suggestions and any corrections.

Thanks

Comment: Is the "preset search criteria" ever changed by another thread?  Does "do something after" do anything with any data that is shared between threads?

Comment: Does `getClonedCriteria` return a synchronized copy, or just a reference copy?

Comment: The preset criteria is NOT changed.

public synchronized static ArrayList<Properties> cloneSearchCriteria(ArrayList<Properties> criteria) {
  if (criteria == null)
   return null;

  ArrayList<Properties> criteriaClone = new ArrayList<Properties>();

  for (Properties sc : criteria) {
   Properties clone = new Properties();
   Enumeration propertyNames = sc.propertyNames();

   while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String) propertyNames.nextElement();
    clone.put(key, (String) sc.get(key));
   }

   criteriaClone.add(clone);
  }

  return criteriaClone;
 }

Comment: sorry. could not format the code..But the cloneSearchCriteria() (that I have  renamed as getClonedCriteria() for this post is synchronized

Comment: You still don't show how the original criteria are initialized. The `cloneSearchCriteria()` method doesn't need to be synchronized if you handle the original criteria properly.

Comment: The original search criteria is spring injected into the caller (which is configured as a singleton in spring). In the spring app context file, this original search criteria is initialized with key value pairs. The caller then calls the utility class  clone method to return a clone of the original search criteria. Not sure if this answers your question

Comment: I meant to ask if I have to synchronize the 
   public static void update(ArrayList<Properties> criteria, String key, String token, String newValue)
    {
        for (Properties sc: criteria)
        {
            String oldValue = sc.getProperty(key);
            if ((oldValue != null) && (oldValue.equals(token))) 
                sc.setProperty(key, newValue);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on your `getClonedCriteria()` method. That's the method that is accessing shared state.

You are creating a "deep copy" of the criteria, so that every clone is independent from the original and from each other.

But there's a more subtle problem, which is that whatever initialization is performed on the prototype criteria must *happen-before* any thread that reads the criteria to clone it. Otherwise, the cloning thread may read an uninitialized version of the data structure.

One way to achieve this is to initialize the prototype criteria in a static initializer and assign it to a class member variable. Another is to initialize the criteria *and then* assign it to a `volatile` variable. Or, you could initialize and assign the prototype (in either order) to an ordinary class or instance member variable inside a `synchronized` block (or using a `Lock`), and then read the variable from another block synchronized on the same lock.

Comment: The original search criteria is spring injected into the caller (which is configured as a singleton in spring) at application startup. In the spring app context file, this original search criteria is initialized with key value pairs. The caller then calls the utility class clone method to return a clone of the original search criteria while processing a web service request(since I want to ensure the original criteria is not altered). Not sure if this is similar to what you are suggestion

Comment: @sbelvadi So, `getClonedCriteria()` is an instance method that looks something like `return cloneSearchCriteria(original)` ? And in that case, `original` (or whatever you named it) is set by Spring injection?

Comment: original is not declared as final or volatile but defined in the spring application context and Dependency Injected into the caller via the spring application context at application startup. In fact in the caller I am obtaining the original search criteria using a getter and the intent to clone is to make any modifications on the copy and not the original. Given this would I have to make the 
    public static void update(ArrayList<Properties> criteria, String key, String token, String newValue)
synchronized?

Comment: No. As long as Spring injection works as advertised, none of this code needs any synchronization. All request-handling threads will see a correctly initialized criteria object, and make an independent copy that is used for that request. Spring is taking care of the thread-visibility issues for you. None of your methods, including `cloneSearchCriteria()` need to be synchronized.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and your patience with my questions.Learning something new every day

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with a race condition. At least the underlying `Properties` data structure will never be corrupted but it could have an incorrect value.  In particular, any number of threads could be in this section meaning the final value could be anything from any thread.

```
        String oldValue = sc.getProperty(key);
        if ((oldValue != null) && (oldValue.equals(token))) 
            sc.setProperty(key, newValue);
```

I am assuming your List is never altered, but if it is, you have to have `synchronized`.  You could lock on the class, but locking on the collection you are altering might be a better choice.

Comment: Not sure if I have understood you correctly.
    public synchronized static ArrayList<Properties> cloneSearchCriteria(ArrayList<Properties> criteria) {
 if (criteria == null)
   return null;

 ArrayList<Properties> criteriaClone = new ArrayList<Properties>();

 for (Properties sc : criteria) {
  Properties clone = new Properties();
  Enumeration propertyNames = sc.propertyNames();

  while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
   String key = (String) propertyNames.nextElement();
   clone.put(key, (String) sc.get(key));
  }

   criteriaClone.add(clone);
 }
 return criteriaClone;
}

Comment: Continuing: are you saying in the update(), I have to have a 
synchronized(criteria){
...
}

Comment: Subsequent edits appear to show a deep copy of the the data. Does your answer still apply?

Comment: @peter - original List is defined in the spring application context and Dependency Injected into the caller via the spring application context at application startup. In fact in the caller I am obtaining the original search criteria using a getter and the intent to clone is to make any modifications on the copy and not the original. Given this would I have to make the 
    `code` public static void update(ArrayList<Properties> criteria, String key, String token, String newValue) synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that each thread has its own stack, so each thread will have its own copies of local variables and method arguments when it calls `update()`. When it runs it will save those local variables and method arguments to its stack.

However, the method argument `criteria` is a reference to a mutable object that will be stored on the heap where Java objects reside. If the threads can call `update()` on the same ArrayList, or the elements contained in the ArrayList could be contained in more than one ArrayList passed into different invocations of `update()` by different threads then synchronization errors could occur.

Comment: The criteria a clone of a preset array list and this clone is local to the calling method. So given this, would the criteria passed to the update() be considered local and not shared since I would be passing a reference.